Multi-file diff'ing - program, plug-in, or just algorithm
I'm finding myself in a workflow where I need to keep track of the differences of several very similar but not exactly same files. The diff command, as well as the mode of the same name in GNU Emacs serve me well when there's 2 files, but efficiency can be increased if just I can diff several files at a time - showing common lines and lines specific to certain files.
Preferably, there can be a program dedicated to this purpose - I'll wildly guess a CLI program of this type can be cross platform since the functionality doesn't require anything beyond what's provided by the C standard library. An Emacs plug-in would also be okay.
Less preferably, maybe there's an algorithm for this, and I'll implement it in code myself.
Addendum 01:

I prefer to have such program in any system that claims conformance to POSIX-2003 (Issue 6 counting from the XPG days).
Command-line is a must, GUI is a plus.
I need to diff at least 10 files for the moment.


For which system? Command line only or usable from withing CLI, but can have GUI? Up to how many files?

@Destroy666 edited.

I don't think there's anything that's CLI-focused and can deal with 10 files. Other than scripting e.g. diff, but that would not have optimal results in terms of length

Not strictly command line but perhaps adaptable as open sourced cross platform python will handle 10 files https://diffuse.sourceforge.net/download.html
Not well updated but easy to alter. and for me the windows version is compiled standalone.exe with over 700 files !!! for dependencies .
So I poorly show just 10 of the source files to produce a crude heads up but you can test 10 of your own.
diffuse 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt

Potential Answer
Second alternative and well known text editor is vim which was default max 4 files. But seems to currently be 8 ? see commit https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/5614
vim -d file1 file2 file3 file4 ..8?
However that supposedly can also be more easily altered using just one edit in source. It used to be a line about 2/3 of the way down in structs.h from version 7.0 onwards.
See https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Avim%2Fvim+DB_COUNT&type=code
